# UiTableView - Add content to relevant sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'll start with saying I'm reasonably new to IOS dev!

I have an array of data which looks like this -

```
    shopObjects *shop2 = [[shopObjects alloc] 
                initWithshopITitle:@"3 for 2 PT Sessions" 
                shopIGroup:@"standard" 
                shopIDesc:@"Special Offer - Get 3 bespoke PT sessions for the price of just one!" shopIPrice:@"00.20"  
                offer:false];
```

the shopIgroup field displays the section name.

I have listed the data into a tableview via the following -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// NOT SURE HOW TO CALCULATE THIS!
return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 // NOT SURE HOW TO CALCULATE THIS!
return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10; 
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"shopItems";
   shopObjects *s = [self.shopArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text=s.shopITitle;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 return cell;
}
```

My questions are -

1. How can I calculate the number of headers and the number of rows in each section required for the return statements in the above methods?
2. How do I then apply my cell to the relevant section?

**UPDATE**
My ShopObjects.m file for reference -

@implementation shopObjects

```
-(id)initWithshopITitle:(NSString *)shopITitleD shopIGroup:(NSString *)shopIGroupD   shopIDesc:(NSString *)shopIDescD shopIPrice:(NSString *)shopIPriceD offer:(Boolean )offerD{
 self= [super init];
  if(self){
    self.shopITitle = shopITitleD;
    self.shopIGroup = shopIGroupD;
    self.shopIDesc = shopIDescD;
    self.shopIPrice = shopIPriceD;
    self.offer = (offerD);



  }
   return self;


 }
```

**ShopObjects.h file**

## import

```
@interface shopObjects : NSObject



@property(strong) NSString *shopITitle;
@property(strong) NSString *shopIGroup;
@property(strong) NSString *shopIDesc;
@property(strong) NSString *shopIPrice;
@property Boolean offer;


-(id)initWithshopITitle:(NSString *)shopITitleD shopIGroup:(NSString *)shopIGroupD shopIDesc:(NSString *)shopIDescD shopIPrice:(NSString *)shopIPriceD offer:(BOOL )offerD;


@end
```

*array setup*

```
    shopObjects *shop1 = [[shopObjects alloc] initWithshopITitle:@"1 x PT Session"     shopIGroup:@"running" shopIDesc:@"1 x 1hour fitness session with Zoe - bespoke fitness session.\n\nZoe's sessions focus on your general health and fitness so she will look at a bespoke fitness schedule that encompasses exersize, healthy eating, sleep and general lifestyle - to help you meet your goals.\n\nBe good to yourslef and give it a go.." shopIPrice:@"10.00"  offer:false];



  shopObjects *shop2 = [[shopObjects alloc] initWithshopITitle:@"3 for 2 PT Sessions" shopIGroup:@"offers" shopIDesc:@"Special Offer - Get 3 bespoke PT sessions for the price of just one!" shopIPrice:@"00.20"  offer:false];



  shopObjects *shop3 = [[shopObjects alloc] initWithshopITitle:@"1 x Running Club" shopIGroup:@"running" shopIDesc:@"1 x running club session - roup event - max group of 10." shopIPrice:@"15.00"  offer:false];


 shopObjects *shop4 = [[shopObjects alloc] initWithshopITitle:@"1 x Weights session" shopIGroup:@"weights" shopIDesc:@"1 x body building sesson" shopIPrice:@"10.90"  offer:false];



  self.shopArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shop1, shop2, shop3,shop4,  nil];
  self.sectionData = [self.shopArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.shopIGroup"];
```

***UPDATE***

For Greg - I have implemented your code and suggestions and app still crashes, I now get -

NSLOG - 
    2013-12-05 10:16:18.595 blah[3321:70b] Value of hello = 0
    2013-12-05 10:16:18.596 blah[3321:70b] Value of hello = 1
    2013-12-05 10:16:18.596 blah[3321:70b] Value of hello = 2
    2013-12-05 10:16:27.962 blah[3321:70b] SECTIONS: 3
    2013-12-05 10:16:27.962 blah[3321:70b] -[**NSCFConstantString shopIGroup]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c7c38
    2013-12-05 10:16:27.965 blah[3321:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString shopIGroup]: unrecognized   selector sent to instance 0x1c7c38'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02bde5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x029618b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02c7b903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02bce90b ___forwarding_** + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02bce4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   blah                            0x000198fb -[shopTVcontroller tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] + 187
    6   UIKit                               0x00a33dc0 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2510
    7   UIKit                               0x00a39384 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 288
    8   UIKit                               0x00a39495 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 68
    9   UIKit                               0x008ae181 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 400
    10  UIKit                               0x008c9333 -[UITableView setContentInset:] + 329
    11  UIKit                               0x008efeba -[UIViewController _setNavigationControllerContentInsetAdjustment:] + 538
    12  UIKit                               0x0091a9bc -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 399
    13  UIKit                               0x0091ab2e -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 64
    14  UIKit                               0x0091b02b -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 235
    15  UIKit                               0x0090f8ff -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 2087
    16  UIKit                               0x0091c0c7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    17  UIKit                               0x0091ccb9 -[UINavigationController **viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    18  UIKit                               0x00a56181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    19  UIKit                               0x0084c267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    20  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0297381f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0221a2ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0220e0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0220df40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    24  QuartzCore                          0x02175ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    25  QuartzCore                          0x02176e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    26  QuartzCore                          0x02177544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x02ba64ce  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x02ba641f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x02b84344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x02b83ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x02b838db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x03c349e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x03c34809 GSEventRun + 104
    34  UIKit                               0x007e1d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225

```
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0314f70d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Error screen - 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get section by get distinct sections of your objects from array. The best way is to add new @property of NSArray type (you will need it later) for example sectionData and in viewDidLoad load it with distinct values:

```
self.sectionData = [self.shopArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.shopIGroup"];
```

Next you can just display a number of distinct object which gives you number of sections

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.sectionData count];
}
```

To get number of rows per section you have to filter the array for section name like that:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Get your section name from distinct array
    NSString *s = self.sectionData[section]
    //Filter your main array
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shopIGroup like %@", s];
    NSArray *filteredArr = [self.shopArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    return [filteredArr count];
}
```

To display the data you have to do something similar as above in cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"shopItems";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    //Get your section name from distinct array
    NSString *s = self.sectionData[indexPath.section]
    //Filter your main array
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shopIGroup like %@", s];
    NSArray *filteredArr = [self.shopArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
   shopObjects *rightS = filteredArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text=rightS.shopITitle;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 return cell;
}
```

I would recommended you to change data structure. In this kind of project I use array(mainArray) with another array embedded (sectionArray) where I keep object. So I know that for example my first array contain another array of object for first section.
And I can yes section like that:

```
[mainArray count]
```

And rows per section like that:

```
 mainArray[section].count
```

And data for each row:

```
mainArray[section][row]
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: thanks for your help greg - just struggling with understanding the  shopObjects *s = self.sectionData[section] line - the code errors saying section is undefined?  Do i need to add 'section' as an array type?
Also the line - ' NSArray *filteredArr = [self.shopArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];' - pred is not recognised..

Comment: Sorry replace [section] with [indexPath.section]. It should do the job. You don't add a section, you read object from array, this is the same as [array objectAtIndex:section] - You are getting object from the index (section). Make sure you have this line NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shopIGroup like %@", s.shopIGroup]; above, this is a line where you create pred. It's in my post.

Comment: cool - makes sense - cheers for your help - all looks good until I run - I get this error when opening the tableviewpage - 2013-12-03 17:06:43.958 GetPTFit[2800:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString shopIGroup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c7c00'

Comment: How do you declare shopIGroup in shopObjects object? Do you know where you get the error from (which line)? Can you post shopObjects class?

Comment: hi Greg - Ive posted myshopObjects.M file above - not sure how I find out which line has triggered the error?

Comment: Use BOOL instead of Bolean, it doesn't change anything but you should use BOOL. Can you post the code where you add your shopObjects objects to the array?

Comment: cool ok cheers - yes I've changed that - ive posted the array setup above

Comment: Do you know which line gives you this error, if not can you try debug it (comment out the code I posted in cellForRowAtIndexPath: if it still doesn't work add code to numberOfSectionsInTableView: NSLog(@"SECTIONS: %d", [self.sectionData count]) before return and add (@"ROWS: %d", [filteredArr count]) in numberOfRowsInSection: before return, watch the console and let me know the output.

Comment: Hi Greg - I commented out the code and the error still appears - I added the above code to the two methods and the app still crashes - but it does display the number of sections in the log - i'll paste the log above and the errors - not sure how i get the line number?

Comment: @Dancer the issue appear in numberOfRowsInSection: method. I amended it for debuting purposes. Can you change it and send output from console?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with declaration of shopObjects class. Can you post interface file of that class?

Comment: @Dancer See now, I make some changes in numberOfRowsInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath: The issue was that when you get distinct sections you store NSString in sectionData array buy I tried to get shopObject object and I called properties for that object which not exists in NSString class. Now it should be ok.

Comment: works a treat - thanks very much for all your help man - much appreciated - i owe you an ale!  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TLIndexPathDataModel`](http://tlindexpathtools.com/api/Classes/TLIndexPathDataModel.html) from [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) instead of an array. It can organize your data into sections and provide a bunch of handy APIs for implementing your data source and delegate methods like `[dataModel numberOfRowsInSection:]` and `[dataModel itemForRowAtIndexPath:]`.

In your case, you'd create your data model like this:

```
NAArray *items = ...;// array of shopObjects
TLIndexPathDataModel *dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:items sectionNameKeyPath:@"shopIGroup" identifierKeyPath:nil];
```